# CeleryBeat issues on Ubuntu

Tags: django, ubuntu, django-celery, celerybeat

I'm noticing weird issues with CeleryBeat. I use it regularly for running period tasks that are very crucial and important for me. Every so often (almost every 2-5 days) I notice that CeleryBeat silently fails. No warnings or errors in the logs (all of them) and it's really confusing me.

Is there any other way to get the information from celerybeat? I have the following options for celery in my celeryd config:

```
# celerybeat
CELERYBEAT_CHDIR=$CELERYD_CHDIR
CELERYBEAT="$CELERYBEAT_CHDIR/manage.py celerybeat"
CELERYBEAT_OPTS="-S djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
CELERYBEAT_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"

CELERYBEAT_USER="ubuntu"
CELERYBEAT_GROUP="ubuntu"
CELERYBEAT_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/beat.log"
CELERYBEAT_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/beat.pid"
```

Is there anything else i'm missing?

**[EDIT]**

The last entry in my celerybeat logs before dying:

```
[2013-11-04 14:13:07,515: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task my_task (celery_tasks.tasks.my_task)
[2013-11-04 14:13:07,577: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2013-11-04 14:16:50,491: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2013-11-04 14:16:50,494: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
```

As you can see, it really has no information. My django log and celery logs are also not filled with any errors.

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: I updated the information with log...but there really isn't much there.

Comment: I'd try changing the log level to DEBUG or ERROR. I found those much more informative for me

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Or did you switch to something else? I am having the same problem and it is maddening!

Comment: Nope, no solution. But I started using `CeleryBeat`. Previously I was putting pending tasks on the queue and thats where I was seeing this issue.